# Conditionally show fields in NetlifyCMS

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

Is there a way in Netlify CMS to show fields conditionally only?

Say I have a Product collection that has categories like : “Rings, bracelets, necklaces…”

I want to display some fields only if a certain category is selected.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [filtered folder collections](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/collection-types/#filtered-folder-collections) for each of your categories is what you're looking for.

Alternatively if you want a more complex UX then it is possible to create [custom widgets](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/custom-widgets/) with conditional formatting.